# Windows Server 2012 One IP per application

Tags: firewall, windows-server-2012-r2, ip

I have a VPS with Windows Server 2012R2 on it and the provider gave me one IPv4 address and an IPv6 /64 subnet. I read the [tutorial the posted on their website](https://contabo.com/?show=tutorials&tutorial=configuring-additional-ip-addresses) and tried to setup another IPv6 address, but I don't know if it is working or not.

Ultimately what I want to achieve is having multiple applications running on the same server but with different IP addresses (IPv4 at the end, but every v4 address is +2€/month, so first I wanted to try it out with v6 addresses).
Example:

App01.exe --> 192.51.100.42

App02.exe --> 171.155.181.41

What I tried is changing the Firefox's IPv6 address with [Windows Firewall](http://i1.wp.com/www.cm3solutions.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/sm_4.jpg) to another, so I can see that it is not using the default. I used [this tutorial](http://www.cm3solutions.com/block-ip-address-ip-range-using-windows-firewall/)  and [this site](http://ipv6.whatismyv6.com/) to check my IPv6 address in firefox, but with no success. Can I achieve this with windows firewall or is there in easier way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows Firewall will not help you with what you're trying to accomplish.

You want to "bind" your applications to a specific network adapter / IP address.

Most server applications should have a configuration option for you to select which IP addresses to listen (bind) on.

Doing this for a client application is a bit unusual and requires a third party tool. [Here is a tool that may help you do that](https://r1ch.net/projects/forcebindip), and [a tutorial for its use](http://www.howtogeek.com/117890/how-to-force-an-application-to-use-a-specific-network-card/). I haven't used it myself, so I can't testify to its efficacy, but according to its claimed feature set, it should do what you want.

Comment: It is not really a tool I would use in a server. Also I tried it out, it does not work with IPv6

Comment: What's the use case? It's a bit of an odd request anyway. Most **server** applications (I.e. applications that are listening for requests) will have an option as to what IP to bind to. Needing to bind a **client** application like Firefox to a specific IP is unusual and will require an unusual solution like this. There is no built-in way in Windows to do what you're asking.

Comment: I want Java applications to run on the same server, but with different IP-s If I want them. So the application should implement this in some way?

Comment: Correct. The application should allow you to bind to a specific IP, or any available IP. Most server applications would have this configurable somewhere.